# Seeing air trapped under ice while underwater

Tags: internal-consistency, underwater, ice

A scene am writing takes place in Summer in the Artic. The character is swimming underwater, under the ice (imagine a small iceberg).
Above her a large bubble of air has formed. Never mind what formed it. It remained locked there because of the uneven shape of the ice bottom.

The swimmer is about 10-20 meters underwater. The ice bottom and bubble of air is 4-5 meters above her. The air bubble is about 4 cubic meters. Outside is daylight and the sun well above the horizon. The light comes sideways into the water and under the blue ice which is very thick (several meters). The bubble may be near the border of the iceberg.

The swimmer is wearing future snorkeling gear (no air tanks) with full face mask. Warmed suit to resist the cold water better.

**Would the swimmer be able to see the air bubble from beneath?**

How else could she detect it if not?

Comment: From experience of being trapped under ice - no. Ice itself look like Stratocumulus clouds. The clearer ice is brighter as is let more light in and it's not any indication of thickness or if there is "less" water beetwen you and the bottom of ice (also ice is very wavy from the water side).

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Am very interested in your experience. Would you like to expand your comment in an answer?

Comment: LSerni answer is very similar to one I would give.

Comment: Do you mean a large pocket, or air like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCkt-WI0n3g

Comment: A side issue (which you may decide to use in your story): O2 is more soluble than N2, hence if the air pocket was trapped a while ago, most of the O2 may have leaked out, leaving a mostly unbreathable air pocket (but one which is not obviously unbreathable).  If this works for the story you're writing, great.  If it doesn't, well, you can assume the air pocket was trapped recently (and just not bring it up to the reader)...

Comment: @DWKraus a large pocket. Large enough to breath for a while. Although there will be problems because of this as she will be 3/4 meters underwater... Beautiful video by the way, inspiring.

Comment: @poncho thank you for the additional issue. The air bubble has been done and is being done very recently. Not the purest of air but ... better than water! For a while at least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Would the swimmer be able to see the air bubble from beneath?

**Only in very specific circumstances** (which your setup *seems* to negate).

Ordinarily (been there, done *almost* that), you won't see any specific difference from below.

Except in this one case, that I can vouch for: if you release bubbles, and you're under the ice with a reasonable light source with you, you will see your bubbles "falling upwards" on the lower surface of the ice. If they hit a larger bubble of air trapped underneath, delimiting a larger area of the lower surface, the bubbles will merge with it and the whole area will start rippling and sending back the light in a fractured way. That is sure to catch your eye, **but** if your future scuba does not release bubbles, or the swimmer is not looking exactly upwards, they won't notice anything.

If you are close enough to the trapped air sac that you look at it at a low enough angle (below the *critical angle*), then Snell's Law comes into play and the air will appear as a mirror. That effect is unmistakable. But **you need to view the bubble under the appropriate angle**, which means being close to its surface (or looking at a distant trapped sac):

[image]

Comment: This reassures me as you have been there! I had planned something like that but what you write reassures me. Most likely she would not notice unless something (air bubbles) may induce her to look up and turn on the lights. She has reasons both to be in snorkeling gear, not scuba, and lights off. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that under 15+ meter of ice one won't be able to see much with naked eye.

[This page](https://mymodernmet.com/iceberg-underwater-tobias-friedrich/) shows very nice pictures of what it looks like to swim under an iceberg

[image: iceberg from underwater]

Notice that when there is no free water surface available, the water is much more dark, and there we see small ice blocks roaming the water surface.

The swimmer might be able to see something from very close when using artificial lights (underwater lights do not have a very long range), but would just notice the air/water interface as being rather flat when compared to the iceberg surface and probably reflective and metal like if seen from the right angle.

A possible way to detect air pockets would be using sonar: the reflectivity of the air/water interface is different from the ice/water interface, due to the larger difference in density.

Comment: Depending on how clear the water is, any turbulence should cause waves in the air pool allowing your eyes to catch the motion.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in the question. The ice is not 15 meters thick. Much less. Could be just 3/4 meters. Too much to break through anyway. Imagine the swimmer is at 8 meters depth, the bottom of the ice may be 4 / 5 meters above her. The air bubble may be half meter thick. These are not hard set numbers though. I can alter them a bit if needed. I imagine the sunlight coming in from the side of the ice, the sun is not overhead. P.S. wonderful images!

Answer (score 6):

**Air bubbles are reflective.  Ice is not.**

[image: bubbles]

https://weather.com/photos/news/underwater-ice-sheet-hockey-austria-tobias-friedrich

These divers have left bubbles under the lake ice.  The bubbles are reflective.  You can see them shimmering above the divers.

There is an even better photo here:
https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-reflection-in-air-bubbles-made-by-divers-under-surface-of-the-ice-86744148.html

Air bubbles in water look like puddles of liquid mercury.  The surfaces are reflective and metallic appearing.  Ice does not have that mirror look.

Your diver would see the reflective shimmer of the bubble.  It will look different from the ice but it might not immediately be clear to her what she is looking at if she has not seen it before.

Comment: You are awesome! Now I know how to describe them. As the swimmer is unexperienced she would not know what they are at first, you are right. But then she will see air bubbles raising up to them and merging with them. That should be enlightening. Especially for someone who is running short of air....

Comment: Little air bubbles will hit the bottom of the ice and then slide along like shiny shoggoths until they merge with the greater bubble.

Comment: Only be aware that the "reflectivity" of the underwater bubble depends on the **viewing angle**, so unless you are close to the surface and look far from the vertical, it will just not be there (see e.g. http://www.daveread.com/uw-photo/comp101/snells_window.html for the math behind the fact)